# How to download a folder/directory from the FTP server using perl?

Tags: perl

I have an array of folders in the FTP serever. For an example,

```
@ftp_dirs=('/Tarun/Netdomais','/Tarun/Testing','/Tarun/Tested_files')
```

I need to download each folders in the array from the FTP server to local folder (c:\ftp_downloaded).

I have written the below lines

```
use strict;
use Net::FTP;


my $ftp=Net::FTP->new("hostname",Debug=>0);
$ftp->login("user_name","password");
$ftp->cwd("/Tarun");

my @ftp_dirs=('/Tarun/Netdomais','/Tarun/Testing','/Tarun/Tested_files');
my $local='c:\ftp_downloaded';

foreach my $ftp_folder(@ftp_dirs){
  $ftp->get($ftp_folder,$local);
}
```

The above code is not working. Because the get method is only applicable for downloading files from the ftp not folders.

Is it possible to download a folder from the ftp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [Net::FTP::Recursive](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aFTP%3a%3aRecursive).

Example:

```
use Net::FTP::Recursive;

$ftp = Net::FTP::Recursive->new("some.host.name", Debug => 0);
$ftp->login("anonymous",'me@here.there');
$ftp->cwd('/pub');
$ftp->rget( ParseSub => \&yoursub );
$ftp->quit;
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, start all your perl scripts with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Second, you miss a `;` after line:

```
my @ftp_dirs=('/Tarun/Netdomais','/Tarun/Testing','/Tarun/Tested_files')
```

Third, I think you could try to use the `command` method inherited by `Net::FTP` from `Net::Cmd` and issue a ftp  `mget` command, or emulate the `mget` with something like:

```
$ftp->get($_) for grep { 1 } $ftp->ls;
```

Comment: I have written the sample snippets only. So that I didn't mention the use strict; like that.... Anyhow I will follow your opinion. Thanks for your advice

Comment: The files only downloaded from the FTP server, while using the code $ftp->get($_) for grep { 1 } $ftp->ls; Can you please suggest some other solutions to download the folders in a directory from the FTP?